# populating NSTableView with objects created from textFields

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield

This is my first question on here. I'm sorry if it's been asked before, but I couldn't find anything while searching. Also, I'm pretty new to programming so please bear with me.

Basically I'm trying to populate my NSTableView with objects from a custom class that are created by filling out text fields and clicking a button.

This is the page where the user would fill out the info for the object they are creating:
[image: Create object page]]

When the Done button is clicked it will bring you to this page containing the table view where the new object you just created should be added:
[image: Table View Page]

This is my my header file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>{
    NSArray *_tradeArray;
    NSMutableDictionary *_tradeDictionary;}

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTabView *myTabView;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *titleTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *volumeTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *publisherTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *upcTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *myTableView;


- (IBAction)tradeLibraryButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backtoMainButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addTradePage:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancelAddTrade:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)FinishAddingTrade:(id)sender;
@end
```

This is my implementation file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "JMTradePaperback.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate


-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        _tradeDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        _tradeArray = [_tradeDictionary allKeys];
        }
    return self;}

- (IBAction)tradeLibraryButton:(id)sender {
    [_myTabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:1];}

- (IBAction)backtoMainButton:(id)sender {
    [_myTabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:0];}

- (IBAction)addTradePage:(id)sender {
    [_myTabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:2];}

- (IBAction)cancelAddTrade:(id)sender {
    [_myTabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:1];}

- (IBAction)FinishAddingTrade:(id)sender {
    JMTradePaperback *aTrade = [[JMTradePaperback alloc]init];
    [aTrade setTitle:[_titleTextField stringValue]];
    [aTrade setVolume:[_volumeTextField stringValue]];
    [aTrade setPublisher:[_publisherTextField stringValue]];
    [aTrade setUpcCode:[_upcTextField stringValue]];
    [_tradeDictionary setObject:aTrade forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _upcTextField.stringValue]];
    [_myTabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:1];
    [_myTableView reloadData];}

-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
    return _tradeArray.count;}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"Title"]){
        JMTradePaperback *item = [_tradeArray objectAtIndex: row];
        return item.title;}
    if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"Volume"]){
        JMTradePaperback *item = [_tradeArray objectAtIndex:row];
        return item.volume;}
    else{
        JMTradePaperback *item = [_tradeArray objectAtIndex:row];
        return item.publisher;}
}
@end
```

Also here is a picture of tableView hooked up to AppDelegate as the datasource, and picture showing that I set up the column Identifiers:
[Datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHruU.png),
[Column Identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faiie.png)

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, but any help at all is really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You are not adding the dictionary you create to _tradeArray.  There are more problems.

Comment: How should I add the dictionary to `_tradeArray`? I've tried a couple different ways, but cannot get it to work. Also, what are the other problems you see?

Comment: If given a chance, I can help you get the above done with very less code, by using cocoa-binding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `_tradeArray` each time you modify the dictionary. As your code currently stands, `_tradeArray` contains the keys of the dictionary as it was when it was initialized and is never changed after that point.

You should declare `_tradeArray` as a mutable array (`NSMutableArray*`). You can initialize it to `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` or, if you prefer, `[[_tradeDictionary allKeys] mutableCopy]`. You would append each key (the UPC) to it at the same point that you add it to the dictionary (assuming the UPC is new and not already in the dictionary).

Comment: I changed  `_tradeArray` to a mutable array and changed it to `_tradeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` in the init method. I tried `_tradeArray = [[_tradeDictionary allKeys]mutableCopy];` in the `FinishAddingTrade` method, but had no luck. i also tried: `[_tradeArray addObject:[_tradeDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _upcTextField.stringValue]]];` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have correctly added table column identifiers, the following should work, I suppose.

```
// AppDelegate.h
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTabView *myTabView;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *titleTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *volumeTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *publisherTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *upcTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *myTableView;
...


// AppDelegate.m
@implementation AppDelegate {
    NSArray *tradeArray;
}
@synthesize myTabView,titleTextField,volumeTextField,publisherTextField,upcTextField,myTableView;

- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    tradeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)FinishAddingTrade:(id)sender {
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:titleTextField.stringValue,@"title",volumeTextField.stringValue,@"volume",publisherTextField.stringValue,@"publisher",nil];
    [tradeArray addObject:dict];
    [myTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return tradeArray.count;
}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSString *title = [[tradeArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex] objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *vol = [[tradeArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex] objectForKey:@"volume"];
    NSString *pub = [[tradeArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex] objectForKey:@"publisher"];

    if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"Title"]) {
        return  ;
    }
    if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"Volume"]){
        return vol;
    }
    else{
        return pub;
    }
}
```

Comment: With this I am getting undeclared identifier errors for `fileArray`. The column Identifiers in for `myTableView` do match the ones in this code, and the appDelegate class is correctly hooked up as the dataSource for `myTableView`.

Comment: I've made silly mistakes.  I've made changes to the last tableView method.

Comment: So, I fixed the second table view method to reflect what you have above. I did have to change the last `row` in the method name to `rowIndex`. Now, everything builds successfully, but I'm still not getting anything in my tableView. I added two pictures to my original question showing how I hooked my tableView dataSource up, and one showing that I set up the Column Identifiers.